# invalid convertion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to c/c++ and I've been working with python for a long time, I didn't take any tutorials, but I got this error when I tried to declare an array of strings.

code:

```
    QString months[12]={'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};
```

error:
        invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

What does that error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes for strings (`"`). `'` is for character literals.

Answer (score 1):

In the Python is not difference between `'` and `"`(are strings) , but in the C++ They are different:

```
char   c = 'c';
string str = "string";
```

Don't forget the C++ has not `'''`, while it was as string in Python.

Your code:

```
 ... "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```